# Phonegap(3.3.0) Navigator.notification.alert can't popup on real device(iPhone5s iOS7)

Tags: ios, cordova, notifications, alert, navigator

I use phonegap Navigator.notification.alert to show a alert one my iPhone app.  
But when I call the Navigator.notification.alert, there is nothing shown on the screen.  
Then when I try to leave the app(double-click the home button),or I leave the app then open it again.  
The alert pop up.  
So I thing the function Navigator.notification.alert was working, but something stoped the alert from popping up on the screen.  
And not just the alert,the Navigator.notification.confirm function also can not popup.  
What would Cause This?  
Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested out and it is working as expected,

Please make sure you installed the notification plugin,

```
$cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```

and check you XML,

```
<feature name="Notification">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification" />
</feature>
```

If still exists use it as an event as mentioned below,

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", showAlert, false);

    function showAlert() {
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'Test Alert on Device Ready!', 
            alertDismissed,  
            'Testing',  
            'Ok'          
        );
    }
        function alertDismissed() {
            // do something
        }
```

For more info [click here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you V_J_S,I checked my plugin config and I am using the function just like you wrote.But I do not have the line "document.addEventListener("deviceready", showAlert, false);", I will add it and test again.

Comment: Hi,@V_J_S.  I test it.But the alert just does not popup.  I debug this use xcode,I find the process go into the navigator.notification.alert and but not go into the CDVnotification.Then when I leave the app(click the home button) process go into the CDVnotification.  So the process stoped between the javascript call and the CDVNotification.m.  And I find this not just happen at iOS7 also at iOS6.

Comment: Just try to create alert in simple hello world app and test it out in ios7 and let me know if this notification fails to display. Thanks

Comment: Hi V_J_S, I found the cause.phonegap and javascript works well,and one  youtube components on my page casue a loop error,so everything goes wrong.When I delete the youtube component from the page. everything works well.Sorry about that.Thank you very much.

Comment: I found iframe can not work well with Phonegap 3.3.0,When there is a iframe on the page.Phonegap 3.3 stop working.Phonegap 3.0.0 have no problem.